# What to do about my infant who sucks his thumb constantly?

Tags: infant, behavior

My 5 month baby boy is always sucking  on his thumb non stop.

Is it okay for him to do it while he's asleep? I try to take it away and he just wont let me.
Sometimes he makes him self sick so I am very careful watching over him.

Answer (score 3):

Our doctors encourage it for our baby.  She has struggled with feeding problems and the one thing we don't want to do is discourage her from putting things into her mouth since we want to get her to put food in and eat it.  The thumb sucking at this age isn't a bad thing at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think its OK let him because he needs to get over it before he is older. If he does it now he will get over wanting to do it in the future. I have seen adults do it because they never had the chance to do it as a child. It's a calming reaction you can also try putting a bobo pasifire but the really gummy one it could help the habit go away over time.

Comment: "If he does it now he will get over wanting to do it in the future." Do you have any support for this statement? This sounds like pure opinion (to me), and not a good basis for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Our doctor also encouraged it due to feeding issues. In my experience as a mother of 1, an aunt of 16, and babysitter of many others: sucking their thumb also helps the child be more self secured in their toddler years.